# Highcharts Tooltip pointFormat conditional formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm facing a problem to show hyphen(-) in place of zero(0) value in the tooltip option in the below approach. When I add conditional statement and its throwing error message.

```
tooltip: {
headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
'<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} %</b></td></tr>',
footerFormat: '</table>',
shared: true,
useHTML: true
}
```

I've attached screenshot for your reference:
[image: highcharts when hovering to the bar]

Can you help me how show hyphen instead of zero in the tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `tooltip.formatter` function:

```
    tooltip: {
        ...,
        formatter: function() {
            var points = this.points,
                result = '<span style="font-size:10px">' + points[0].key + '</span><table>';

            points.forEach(p => {
                result += '<tr><td style="color:' + p.series.color + ';padding:0">' + p.series.name + ': </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>' + (p.y !== 0 ? Math.round(p.y * 10) / 10 : 'hyphen') + ' %</b></td></tr>';
            });

            result += '</table>';

            return result;
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v7oqasb5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter